# Перевод кода из паскаля в с++

Tags: c++, pascal

Кто может перевести код из Паскаля в с++
Сама задача заключается в том, чтобы упорядочить массив по возрастанию. Помогите, пожалуйста

```pascal
 var  mass:array [1..100] of real;
 i, j, n: integer;
 x: real;
begin
 read(n);
 for i:=1 to n do
   read(mass[i]);

 for i := 2 to n do
   begin
     x := mass[i];
     j := i-1;
     while (j>0) and (x<mass[j]) do
       begin
         mass[j+1] := mass[j];
         j := j-1;
       end;
     mass[j+1] := x;
   end;
 for i:=1 to n do
   write(mass[i]:8:2);
end.
```

Comment: А зачем переводить? Почему вы не хотите написать с нуля на С++?

Comment: Сортировку вставками - а это именно она - нетрудно написать и на Срр

Answer (score -3):

Задача похожа на одну из тех, что дают в учебных заведениях. Вот простейший переведенный код. Убедительная просьба: перед тем, как отправлять его преподавателю, разберитесь в нем.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float mass[100];
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> mass[i];
    }
    
    for (int i=1; i<n; ++i) {
        float x = mass[i]; 
        int j = i-1;
        
        while (j>=0 && x<mass[j]) {
            mass[j+1] = mass[j];
            --j;
        } 
        mass[j+1] = x;
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        std::cout << mass[i] << " ";
    }
}
```